# _AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'p1' SocketIO with Flask

Tags: flask, websocket, bokeh

I am using Flask to render graph from bokeh-server

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit
import flask

from bokeh.plotting import figure, push
from bokeh.models import Range1d
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.embed import autoload_server
from bokeh.session import Session
from bokeh.document import Document
from bokeh.models.renderers import GlyphRenderer
from flask.globals import current_app

app = Flask("Graph Realtime",static_url_path='/static')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    y1 = [0, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 5, 6, 25, 28, 4, 7]
    # select the tools we want
    TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

    # the red and blue graphs will share this data range
    xr1 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)
    yr1 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)

    # build our figures
    p1 = figure(x_range=xr1, y_range=yr1, tools=TOOLS, plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
    p1.scatter(x1, y1, size=12, color="red", alpha=0.5)

    document = Document()
    session = Session(root_url='http://localhost:5006/', load_from_config=False)
    session.use_doc('graph')
    session.load_document(document)
    document.clear()  # Semi-optional - see below
    document.add(p1)    # Put it on the server
    session.store_document(document)

    app_con = current_app._get_current_object().app_context()
    app_con.g.p1 = p1.select(dict(type=GlyphRenderer))[0].data_source
    script = autoload_server(p1, session)
    return render_template('index.html', script=script)
```

I am saving the data source to g variable so that I can update it.

```
@socketio.on('my event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    with app.app_context():
        print flask.g.p1
    emit('my response', {'data': 'data'})
```

I am trying to update p1 if 'my event' happens. 
But trying to access g variable raises error AttributeError: "'_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'p1'" error.
What am I doing wrong? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use the "normal" way to access `g` in the `index()`? I mean like this: `from flask import g`. In my test app your method to access `g` is not working, it produces just an empty dict.

Comment: I tried normal way too, it doesnt seem to work either. Did you have any luck with normal way ?